# How to get length of the characters in the inputtex dynamically in primefaces through java class

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to get length of the characters  in the inputtext dynamically  in primefaces  through java class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ajax event "keyup" on the inputText

```
<p:inputText id="firstname" value="#{controller.field}">
   <p:ajax event="keyup" action="#{controller.count}" />
</p:inputText>
```

On your controller :

```
    private String field;

    public int count() {
        return field.lenght();
    }
   public String getField() {
        return field;
    }
    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field= field;
    }
```